# BigQuery how to reference field value from previous record on a multi field key sort

Tags: google-bigquery

A BigQuery newbie question...

I have a BigQuery table like....

```
EventTimestamp (timestamp)
PersonId (int)
Asset (string)
Frequency (string)
Format (string)
Value (int)
Changed (boolean)
```

If I sort the records by...

```
eventTimestamp asc, PersonId,Asset,Frequency,Format
```

I want to set the value of the 'changed' field to 'true' using the following logic...

```
if current record/personid = previous record/personid 
AND 
current record/asset = previous record/asset
and
current record/frequency = previous record/frequency
and
current record/format = previous record/format then
   if current record/value <> previous record/value then
      changed = true
   else
      changed = false
else
   changed = true
end
```

Any suggestions about how to build a BigQuery SQL statement to delivery this?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of typing the exact query you need right now, I'll help with the goal of this question: "How to reference field value from previous record on a multi field key sort".

To reference previous records, use the window function `LAG()`:

```sql
SELECT FlightDAte, Reporting_Airline, Origin, Dest, Tail_Number
  , ActualElapsedTime
  , LAG(ActualElapsedTime) 
    OVER(PARTITION BY Tail_Number 
      ORDER BY Reporting_Airline DESC, year, month, FlightDate) previous_row
FROM `fh-bigquery.flights.ontime_201908`
WHERE DATE_TRUNC(FlightDate, MONTH) = "2018-03-01"
AND Reporting_Airline = 'UA'
LIMIT 100
```

[image]

As you want a boolean, use that result and compare it to the column next to it:

```sql
  ActualElapsedTime = LAG(ActualElapsedTime) OVER(
      PARTITION BY Tail_Number 
      ORDER BY Reporting_Airline DESC, year, month, FlightDate)
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT *, 
  Value != IFNULL(LAG(Value) OVER(PARTITION BY PersonId, Asset, Frequency, `Format` ORDER BY eventTimestamp), -Value) changed
FROM `project.dataset.table`
```